# Calender.YEAR not printing the right value

Tags: java, jsp, date, calendar

I'm parsing the Date that received from user query and another date from XML file.
When I want to get just the YEAR, it print 1 instead of year, by using:

```java
calender.YEAR
```

This is the code:

```java
Elements date = doc.getElementsByTag("DATE");

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(obj.tryParse(dateFrom));
Date xmlDate = dateFormat.parse(obj.tryParse(date.get(0).text()));

Calendar calInput = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calXml = Calendar.getInstance();

calInput.setTime(inputDate);
calXml.setTime(xmlDate);

System.out.println(calInput.YEAR +" "+ calXml.YEAR +" = "+calInput.getTime().toString()+"|||"+ calXml.getTime().toString());
if(calInput.YEAR != calXml.YEAR)
    continue;
```

And this is a sample of the output:

```
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 2004
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
Info:   1 1 = Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2003|||Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IDT 2002
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj ,  it should print 2003 and 2004 etc. !
why it print 1 1 !?

Comment: Because you're printing a constant with the value `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calXml.YEAR` should be written [`Calendar.YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR), because it is a constant (`public static final`) value to be used as a parameter to methods like [`get(int field)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) and [`add(int field, int amount)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29).

To get the year, call `calXml.get(Calendar.YEAR)`.

Comment: Because of Java weirdness, be aware that `MONTH` values are 0-11, not 1-12.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385517/642706) by Andreas is correct.

## java.time

Alternatively, you can use the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. The old date-time classes are a mess and should be avoided.

Convert from java.util.Date to java.time.Instant. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = yourJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Apply a time zone. Your Question's code implicitly depends on the JVM’s current default time zone. I suggest that it is better to explicitly specify your desired/expected time zone. The time zone is critical in determining a date and therefore the year.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Now we can extract the year number.

```
int year = zdt.getYear();
```

Or more interesting, we can get a [`Year`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) object.

```
Year year = Year.from( zdt );
Boolean isLeapYear = year.isLeap();
int yearNumber = year.getValue();
```